# How can I use nPr in (print every r th character from n length) string?

Tags: c++, string, permutation

Suppose we have a string `s="aeiou"`. I want to print every unique rth character form the string.
I mean expected output (when r=2) - ***ae ai ao au ei eo eu io iu ou***.
My approach for this problem is-

```
string str="aeiou";
    set<string>st;
    for(int i=0;i<str.size();++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<str.size();++j)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                string p="";
                p+=str[i];
                p+=str[j];
                sort(p.begin(),p.end());
                st.insert(p);
            }
        }
    }
    for(auto it=st.begin();it!=st.end();++it)
    {
        cout<<(*it)<<" ";
    }
```

Here the complexity is **O(n2)**. Can I do it in **O(n)** or any better approach for that ?

Comment: The *size of the required output* is O(n^2), so no, you cannot do better than O(n^2) to generate it.

Comment: Currently your code iterates n^2 times. You can change the inner loop to `for(int j=i+1;j<str.size();++j)` and remove the lines `if(i!=j)` and `sort(p.begin(),p.end());`. That will reduce the number of iterations to (n^2)/2. But that's still O(n^2)

Comment: There is a bit manipulation method to do this, the complexity will remain the same, but since bitwise operations are faster, the performance of your code will increase.